# Пример асинхронной передачи данных через потоки данных

Tags: c#, асинхронность, потоки-данных, .net-core

Можете показать пример, как написать 2 асинхронные задачи, чтобы они использовали один и тот же Stream (одна пишет, другая читает)? Ну и еще я хочу иметь возможность закинуть их в одну коллекцию и вызвать через Task.WhenAll(). При этом нужно чтобы записывающая таска не писала все данные разом, а отсылала их кусками.
Пример:

```
private static async Task Write(Stream stream)
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    await writer.WriteAsync("aba");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    await writer.WriteAsync("caba");
}
```

```
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
var tasks = new[] { Write(stream), Read(stream) };
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
```

Результат должен выглядеть, например, чтобы в консоль сначала вывело "aba" (ну или не целиком, пусть это определяется размером буфера) и спустя секунду - оставшаяся часть строки

Как должен выглядеть метод Read? Или я использую нежизнеспособный подход и задача об асинхронном использовании стрима решается как-то иначе?

Естественно, выгружать условную строку в оперативную память целиком - не вариант, я использую стримы как раз для того чтобы обрабатывать переданные данные динамически

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по задаче, вы выбрали неверный инструмент. Для того что вам нужно, используется другой класс - `Channel`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Channel<string> channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();
    await Task.WhenAll(ReadAsync(channel.Reader), WriteAsync(channel.Writer));
}

static async Task ReadAsync(ChannelReader<string> reader)
{
    await foreach (string text in reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        Console.Write(text);
    }
}

static async Task WriteAsync(ChannelWriter<string> writer)
{
    await writer.WriteAsync("aba");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    await writer.WriteAsync("caba");
    writer.Complete(); // сообщает каналу, что данных больше нет, чтобы Reader завершился
}
```

- [Introduction to System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/)

Comment: А для чего тогда существуют асинхронные методы для MemoryStream?

Comment: @Scrzii конкретно в MemoryStream они не нужны, это методы родителя Stream. А Stream это может быть и FileStream и NetworkStream, где асинхронная работа обязательна. Вообще то что вы хотите сделать - это шаблон многопоточного программирования Producer/Consumer. Stream не является его реализацией и не подходит по определению. Channel является.

Comment: Таки и где в этом всём асинхронные стримы то? Вопрос про асинхронные стримы, а не про неправильное их применение в каком либо кейсе.

Comment: @InterceptorTSK вы можете оформить свой ответ, не понимаю, к чему этот комментарий здесь.

Comment: Конкретно для передачи массивов байт или символов Channel некузяв, лучше использовать System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe (оба конца которого при необходимости могут быть превращены в Stream)

Comment: @PavelMayorov допустим, а канал чем плох? И автор про строки писал. Если передачу массивов таким образом совместить с пулом массивов, может получиться вполне эффективное решение. Как по перфе, так и по ресурсам. И даже круче любого стрима, потому что в стрим надо сначала писать, потом из него читать, а здесь просто объект передается в неизменном виде.

Comment: Что бы объект "передавать" в неизменном виде - требуется референс на объект. И больше ничего не требуется.

Comment: @InterceptorTSK всё так.