# Странное поведение File.AppendAllText

Tags: c#, windows, .net-6

В упрощённом виде мой код выглядит следующим образом:

```
async Task Foo() {
    while(true) {
        ...
        lock (syncObj) {
            ...
            File.AppendAllText(FileName, data);
        }
    }
}

void Main() {
    ...
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Foo, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap());
    ...
}
```

Очень редко я получаю `IOException`: The process cannot access the file 'path' because it is being used by another process. Как такое возможно, если доступ к файлу синхронизирован конструкцией lock? Больше нигде в коде доступ к файлу не осуществляется и другие процессы с файлом не работают. Возможно это какая то особенность WinAPI вызова, стоящего за `AppendAllText`, и редко выполнение может завершится раньше того момента как файл будет освобожден?

.NET 6.0, Windows

Comment: "другие процессы с файлом не работают" - вы уверены? Точно нет никакого антивируса, например?

Comment: Антивируса нет. Вообще пустой сервер почти. ОС: Windows Server 2022. Такая ситуация не впервые. На других машинах тоже пару раз случалась с другой программой где аналогично ставилась блокировка.

Comment: Но запись идёт очень интенсивная. Каждые ~20 сек 200 потоков пишет.

Comment: _запись идёт очень интенсивная_ - серьёзно? И вы используете `File.AppendAllText`? Этот метод каждый раз открывает и закрывает файл - это _очень_ медленные операции!

Comment: Если задача `LongRunning`, значит подразумевается нагрузка на процессор. При этом запись в файл синхронная. Значит, методу `Foo` как бы и незачем быть асинхронным. / Либо просто пишем `tasks.Add(Foo());` / Короче, нужно видеть больше кода.

Comment: _"Значит, методу Foo как бы и незачем быть асинхронным"_ - Дело в том что есть и другие не LongRunning задачи. _"Короче, нужно видеть больше кода"_ - Я не спрашиваю совета по улучшению кода, я просто хочу узнать почему конкретно метод `AppendAllText` так себя повёл) `StreamWriter` определённо выгоднее использовать, эта часть не была продумана, но само исключение странное.

Comment: Исключение действительно странное, но только в том случае, если доступ к файлу осуществляется только под локом. Не открыт ли он в это же время в IDE или другом редакторе? Нет ли банальной ошибки в коде, что он ещё где-то используется. Что, если запустить профилирование и отследить все обращения к файлу?

Comment: Выполнение происходит вне IDE. Доступ к файлу 100% в одном месте и под lock.

Comment: Угу, это в приложении в одном месте. А стоит открыть его где-то ещё...

Comment: Безотносительно решения проблемы, не используйте синхронные функции в асинхронном методе. Вместо `lock` используйте `await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();`, и `await AppendAllTextAsync` вместо синхронного добавления в файл.

Comment: @CrazyElf Я так понимаю `AppendAllTextAsync` нужно использовать с `ConfigureAwait(true)`, чтобы `Release` для семафора отработал правильно.

Comment: @D.Stark: Насколько я понимаю, можно опускать семафор в любом потоке. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-8.0#thread-safety

Comment: @VladD В этом разделе написано лишь что класс потокобезопасен - это и так понятно. Ситуация здесь несколько иная - захвачен семафор может быть в одном потоке, а продолжение задачи после какого-нибудь await может быть выполнено в другом потоке. Отработает ли Release корректно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использование `lock` внутри асинхронной функции противопоказано. Как я понимаю, это что-то похожее на логирование. В этом случае нужно минимизировать количество операций ввода-вывода, тем самым поднять производительность записи и снизить нагрузку на диск. Не нужно 200 раз в секунду открывать/закрывать файл на запись, это медленно. Как показал @rotabor, здесь сгодилась бы очередь.

И да, вы правы в том что в некоторых случаях операционная система может не успеть отпустить файл после закрытия, так как в зависимости от производительности файловой системы, в редких случаях закрытие файла может выполниться асинхронно, и в теории вы можете словить то самое исключение.

Я предлагаю объединять операции записи в группы. То есть с определённой периодичностью вычитываем буфер и пишем в файл одной операцией, затем ждём следующую порцию при закрытом файле.

```
private readonly Channel<string> _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<string>();

async Task Foo()
{
    ChannelReader<string> reader = _channel.Reader;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!await reader.WaitToReadAsync())
                return; // данных больше не будет, вызван Complete()
            using var sw = File.AppendText(FileName);
            while (reader.TryRead(out string data))
            {
                await sw.WriteAsync(data);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) { } // файл занят, попробовать ещё раз
    }
}
```

Писать в канал - потокобезопасная операция.

```
ChannelWriter<string> logger = _channel.Writer;
string text = "Hello!";
logger.TryWrite(text); // всегда вернёт true для Unbounded канала.
```

Суть решения в том, что файл не будет закрываться и переоткрываться на каждую запись. Канал будет ждать, когда придут данные, как только они придут, файл откроется и будет производиться непрерывная запись до тех пор, пока очередь строк на запись не будет полностью вычищена. Затем файл закроется и будет ожидаться следующая порция данных. Гарантию, что данные не пропадут и будут записаны если не с первой, то со следующей попытки, даст `try-catch`.

При завершении работы приложения просто вызовите `logger.Complete()`, чтобы закрыть канал (навсегда) и метод `Foo` завершится нормальным образом. По сути, это реализация шаблона проектирования Producer/Consumer. Вам нужно запустить всего один раз метод `Foo`, чтобы он обработал всё что попадёт в канал до конца. Либо если файлов для записи несколько, то столько методов, сколько есть файлов. Для каждого файла потребуется свой отдельный канал.

Почитать про каналы: [Introduction to System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал это через Task.ContinueWith, и никакой syncObj не нужен. У меня прекрасно работает.

```
    readonly Queue<string> _events = new ();
    Task _lasttask = Task.CompletedTask;

    void DataChanged(string data) {
        try {
            lock (_events) _events.Enqueue(data);
            _lasttask = _lasttask.ContinueWith(Foo);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    void Foo() {
        try {
            lock (_events) data = _events.Dequeue(); 
            File.AppendAllText(FileName, data);
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Инициализация переменных условно объединена с объявлением.

Comment: @rotabor Обратите внимание, что внутри метода цикл. Да и к тому же, как присоединение продолжения вообще повлияет на поведение `AppendAllText`? Так же понадобилась бы блокировка и ситуация получается аналогичная.

Comment: Цикл я видел, но придал ему значения. Он там, вообще, зачем? Как это работает? data либо пустое, либо нет? А ContinueWith легко и просто создаёт очередь задач. По событию новая задача ставится в очередь. Нужен Queue, туда ложится data, потом "ContinueWith(Foo)" (упрощённо). Ща найду кусок кода.

Comment: По вопросу вопроса ничего сказать не могу, но предложил альтернативное решение.

Comment: "Как это работает? data либо пустое, либо нет?" - Нет, всё устроено намного сложнее. Приведённый код лишь для демонстрации, как я уже говорил. Внутри подгружаются и обрабатываются данные, в конце идёт отметка о статусе проведенных операций в виде записи в файле.

Comment: "По событию новая задача ставится в очередь." - Я понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, но учитывая остальной код, который вы не видите, это здесь ни к чему.

Comment: Ну, дело хозяйское.

Comment: @rotabor https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1

Comment: `_events.Dequeue()` - нет такого метода у `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: @aepot Ну, на нет и суда нет. А могли бы сделать. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Зачем делать асинхронную функцию, внутри которой синхронизировать доступ к файлу? Что за бред?

Вынесите взаимодействие с файлом вообще куда-то. Сделайте нормальный асинхронный метод с `async`/`await`. Доступ к файлу реализуйте через StreamWriter и всё у вас будет прекрасно.

---

Тут напрашивается паттерн Producer/Consumer. Множество потоков пишут в потокобезопасную коллекцию (лучше всего взять современный `Channel`), один поток выгребает сообщения из канала и пишет в файл.
На SO есть [примеры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1566432/184217) использования `Channel`.

Comment: Это тоже вариант. В общем, через один диспетчер так или иначе.

Comment: _"Зачем делать асинхронную функцию, внутри которой синхронизировать доступ к файлу? Что за бред?"_ - Я указал, что приведенный код служит лишь для демонстрации проблемного места. В методе множество await и кроме того существуют другие не LongRunning задачи. Использование `StreamWriter` как вариант, тогда файл будет безраздельно в собственности потока. Но а по теме вопроса что скажете - `AppendAllText` не должен себя так вести.

Comment: @D.Stark, зачем вам нужен именно `AppendAllText`? Воспользуйтесь другими практиками. В этом и суть программирования, что для одной задачи есть 100500 вариантов решения

Comment: Я понимаю это. Вопрос вообще не об этом. Вопрос стоит о поведении конкретного метода. Я спрашиваю не для решения проблемы, которое простое и очевидное, а из интереса.

Comment: Зачем ответ такого плана делать общим? Отменил.

Comment: @aepot, на форуме нет документации, когда используются общие ответы, а просто сказано, что за них я могу получить больше репутации. Нуу... Почему бы и нет?

Comment: @Faraday за общий ответ не даст вам больше репутации, это заблуждение. Второе заблуждение о том что здесь форум. Не форум, а база знаний.

Comment: @aepot, вот прямое описание того, что написано в описании кнопки "общий": Если вы отметите этот ответ как «общий», порог репутации, необходимый для редактирования, будет понижен, и его сможет редактировать больше участников. Однако голосование за него не принесёт вам баллов репутации. Это действие невозможно отменить. Далее. В разделе "Соглашения" чётко пишет, что это система "вопросов - ответов", что более похоже на форум чем на базу знаний. База знаний это может быть Википедия, а не система "вопросов - ответов", что как бы больше подходит под формулировку "ФОРУМ"

Comment: @Faraday Форум - для общения. Здесь мы не общаемся, а собираем знания для будущих посетителей в формате вопрос-ответ, следим за качеством и вопросов и ответов, поэтому у опытных участников есть права на редактирование чужих вопросов и ответов. На каком форуме вы имеете право редактировать чужие сообщения без прав модератора? Здесь это можно и нужно делать. Форум - это не здесь. Мало того, слово "форум" пишут здесь только некоторые новички, которые в принципе не знакомые с тем, что такое StackOverflow. Или вы думаете, что я как модератор плохо знаю о том, что модерирую?